# Divergence numbers in logo: Steins;Gate easter egg?

Tags: steins-gate

So I recently remembered the Steins;Gate anime and upon searching the logo in google, there appear to be what I think are divergence numbers behind the letters. You can plainly see a complete string of numbers in the letter **i**. If you zoom in enough, there are also a bunch of scattered, unconnected(?) ones hiding in the letters **n**, **s**, **G**, **t** and **e**. A zero (0) can also be found in the dot of the "i", but it's a bit of a stretch. Or not.

My question is: What world line do these numbers correspond to in the anime or VN? Or are they just random numbers used in the logo for design purposes?

[image: Steins;Gate anime logo]

Comment: 0.571024 is the first worldline shift; one could say that's "where it all started." For the other numbers, there's an 8 and a 5; as far as I know no worldline had both those numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Eric notes in the comments](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15352/steinsgate-easter-egg-divergence-numbers-in-logo#comment20090_15352), 0.571024 (the number down the side of the "i") is the divergence number of the worldline Okabe is in at the very beginning of the show.

The numbers hidden in the letters (0 in i / 4 in n / 8 in s / 5 in G / 9 in t / 6 in e) form "048596". I bet there's a "1" hidden somewhere I'm not seeing (maybe in the first "t"?), since 1.048596 is also an important divergence number: that's the divergence number of the Steins;Gate.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Yes it's in the first **t**, I think, since it has a weird vertical line on it that the other **t** didn't have. It was just so long ago that I've already forgotten these numbers. Time to re-watch it, I guess.